# Import namespace in Play framework view

Tags: java, playframework

If I need to make a new object out a class in a Play view, how can I import the class namespace in the view? Sure, most of the times I can just create the new object in the controller and pass it to the view, but I need to create it based on conditions only available  while rendering the view.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the fully qualified object name. Example

```
models.MyObject obj = new models.MyObject();
```

Answer (score 5):

In Play 2, you can add to the `templatesImport` sbt property in your `project/Build.scala`:

```
  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    templatesImport += "model._"
  )
```